# Inconsistency between if + else and if -> unless

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, railstutorial.org

I had an issue today with defining custom RSpec matchers that I resolved, but couldn't actually see any reasoning behind why one of the approaches works and the other doesn't, here's the code:

Approach 1 -- if + else:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_success_message do |message|
  match do |page|
    if message.nil?
      page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success')
    else
      page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: message)
    end
  end
end
```

Approach 2 -- if followed by unless

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_success_message do |message|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') if message.nil?
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: message) unless message.nil?
  end
end
```

I figure the first approach is better because it checks the condition only once, but nevertheless, the result should be the same, right?

Well, it turns out the tests with the first approach pass, while the tests with the second don't. I am completely clueless as to why that is and would love if anyone could shed some light on that.

Edit:

Forgot to add the actual tests (with approach 2):

With the following HTML tag present:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Profile updated</div>
```

I run 4 separate tests:

```
it { should have_success_message } # fails
it { should have_success_message('Profile updated') } # passes
it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') } # passes
it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: "Profile updated") } # passes
```

The failure is with following message:

```
1) User pages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_success_message }
   expected #<Capybara::Session> to have success message
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:80:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When the HTML tag is not present, all 4 tests fail.

Edit 2:

I've tried another approach to verify whether control flow is correct:

Approach 3:

```
if message.nil?
  puts "In if, message is: #{message.inspect}"
  page.should(have_selector('div.alert.alert-success'))
end
unless message.nil?
  puts "In unless, message is: #{message.inspect}"
  page.should(have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: message))
end
```

With this approach the behavior is the same as with approach 2 - first test fails, following 3 pass.

Output is the following:

> In if, message is: nil
>   In unless, message is: "Profile updated"

So the control flow looks alright, but

```
page.should(have_selector('div.alert.alert-success'))
```

fails, even though it passes outside the matcher. This truly is a mystery.

Final edit:

Just in response to the approved answer - when I switch the code like this:

```
page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: message) unless message.nil? 
page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') if message.nil?
```

The tests look like this:

```
it { should have_success_message } # passes
it { should have_success_message('Profile updated') } # fails
it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') } # passes
it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: "Profile updated") } # passes
```

So I think that indeed the last line, when it's not true, gets evaluated to nil, and that causes the whole mess. The first approach is better anyway, but I'm glad I have this problem out of my mind :)

Comment: Maybe it's a binding/priority issue?  What if you do `page.should(have_selector...) if ...` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it still fails

Comment: Tried to clear it up the best I could, as mentioned in the edit I ran the tests you asked and got them to pass.

Comment: That's correct. Trying the test results in a failure, so for some reason it still skips the if

Comment: Also when I remove the flash, all 4 fail

Comment: Thanks for running all the tests I posted-- your answers enabled me see the problem wasn't a bug in RSpec or the custom matcher, which led me to look for the match block. I've cleaned up my answer and my red-herring comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct behavior for RSpec, even though it seems unexpected.

Consider this code:

```
x = nil
"foo" if x.nil?
"bar" unless x.nil?
#=> 
"foo"
nil
```

The `...unless` statement returns `nil` when the condition is falsey.

In your custom matcher, the `...unless` statement returns nil when your message is nil.

That's the last line in your match block, so your match block returns nil.

Then RSpec sees your match block return nil, which RSpec considers the same as false, so  RSpec reports your custom matcher failed.

Comment: Okay, so the first two tests pass, changing to if-not doesn't change anything, using the new syntax also doesn't change the behavior

Comment: First block: success, success, failure, success. Second block: failure, success, failure, failure. Third block: all failures

Comment: I'll edit your post with the output results from my third approach (code in the op edit)

Comment: I think your answer is correct - when I switch the statements so that unless is first, and if second, the test that failed passes, and the one that passed fails. It makes a lot of sense as well, and will let me sleep through the night, thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome! This is new info for me, so thank you for a learning opportunity!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that was a neat puzzle! The key is that the `match` method is expected to return a boolean result. In the first option, the implicit return value is the result of the `if` branch, which is `true`.

Why is it `true`? Well, `should` is [defined](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/expectations/syntax.rb#L53) like this:

```
      def should(matcher=nil, message=nil, &block)
        ::RSpec::Expectations::PositiveExpectationHandler.handle_matcher(self, matcher, message, &block)
      end
```

It delegates to [`PositiveExpectationHandler`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb#L17), whose `handle_matcher` method looks like this:

```
  def self.handle_matcher(actual, matcher, message=nil, &block)
    check_message(message)
    ::RSpec::Matchers.last_should = :should
    ::RSpec::Matchers.last_matcher = matcher
    return ::RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::PositiveOperatorMatcher.new(actual) if matcher.nil?

    match = matcher.matches?(actual, &block)
    return match if match

    message ||= matcher.respond_to?(:failure_message_for_should) ?
                matcher.failure_message_for_should :
                matcher.failure_message

    if matcher.respond_to?(:diffable?) && matcher.diffable?
      ::RSpec::Expectations.fail_with message, matcher.expected, matcher.actual
    else
      ::RSpec::Expectations.fail_with message
    end
  end
```

We can see that if the matcher returns `true` (or actually any truthy value), this is returned from the function and implicitly becomes the return value of `should`. I'm not sure if this behaviour is documented anywhere.

In the second option, however, the value of the last expression/statement wins, and because the `unless` condition is `true`, the expression evaluates to `nil`:

```
1.9.3-p0 :001 > x unless true
 => nil
```

So RSpec thinks the matcher is trying to report failure because you're returning `nil` by accident.

---

To fix this, you probably should_not use `should` in the matcher. You can call through to Capybara's `HaveSelector` matcher like this:

```
if message.nil?
  have_selector('div.alert.alert-success').matches? page
else
  have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: message).matches? page
end
```

Incidentally, specifying `text: nil` eventually trickles through to [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/helpers.rb#L29) where it will result in the empty regexp, so the check for `nil` is not needed anyway and you can write the matcher like this:

```
match do |page|
  have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: message).matches? page
end
```

Not very Rubyesque, I'll admit, but there you go.